# Windows 10 IoT Core Startup App Headed vs Headless

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 running Windows 10 IoT Core with various UWP applications deployed to the device.

I'm happy changing what my default application is on startup either via the web portal settings or in PowerShell. However I don't understand what the difference is between a **headed** and **headless** application. Could someone offer an explaination please? The web portal table now includes an 'App Type' field as well suggesting 'Background' or 'Foreground' but this seems to confuse things further.

[image]

Background = Startup?

Foreground = Default?

To put it another way, would it be possible to have 1x headed UWP application collecting sensor values via the GPIO pins at the same time as a headless UWP application listening for BLE devices? Or the other way around.

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have one headed app that can run at startup (default app) and as many headless apps running at startup as you need.

Answer (score 3):

Headed (foreground): App you can see on the screen with a Mainpage as a start for your app
Headless (background): Is an app runing in background, you don't see anything on the screen like a Windows service.

Comment: Great thanks @t.bel. So I could have 2x UWP apps running on start up collecting different sensor data? The headless one just wouldn't be visable via the display output.

Comment: Yes I think it would be possible but why no use only one app?

Comment: Just for controllability I guess. My example of use probably wasn't the best. Really I just wanted to understand headed vs headless. Thanks